# Macro button broken in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, button, excel-2013

Macro previously working in Excel 2010 does not work in 2013.   Running Windows 7.
In debugging, I found that running the Macro manually works correctly.   However, unable to get the button to execute the Macro(s) associated.   3 Macros in total;  I can provide actual code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (deleting then) creating the buttons in 2013 and seeing if they work in 2010 as well? Just make sure the project was created in 2010 and add the buttons in 2013 if you have access to both versions.

Also are you using activex buttons? or form control buttons? In my experience form control buttons are a little less buggy.

Hope these help